# Sort a list of messages based on created_at date, with DISTINCT and LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, sql, sorting, left-join, distinct

I currently have a list of messages sent from a particular user to other users. This list contains information on the ID of the recipients, as well as the time the message was sent (along with other columns).

I need to sort this list based on the time the message was sent, while also keeping the messages unique by the recipients. Furthermore, I need to LEFT JOIN information from a users database which contains columns on the first and last names of the recipients.

To do this, I am using the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT ON (uc.to_user_id)
        uc.id,
        uc.to_user_id,
        uc.created_at,
        u.first_name,
        u.last_name
FROM user_communication uc
LEFT JOIN "user" u ON (u.id = uc.to_user_id)
WHERE uc.from_user_id = :user_id
```

Where user_id is a parameter that was passed into PHP.

However, this query does not sort the list of messages by the time the messages were sent. The messages cannot be ordered by date_created because of the use of DISTINCT on uc.to_user_id.

Currently, the output looks like:

```
"communications": [
        {
            "id": "1da9f6ea-8b4d-11e6-8698-2bd5d7c3680b",
            "created_at": "2016-10-05 22:43:20",
            "user": {
                "user_id": "a1cc4284-60cd-11e6-a419-e7a2176c4be3",
                "first_name": "Test",
                "last_name": "Account"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "05d6c44a-1be7-11e8-be13-abe8f9af8d9c",
            "created_at": "2018-02-27 17:52:48",
            "user": {
                "user_id": "c84d2ff0-f537-11e6-b318-f7c577b9597c",
                "first_name": "test",
                "last_name": "test"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "16cc5d64-1be7-11e8-87dd-7fa156fb7904",
            "created_at": "2018-02-27 17:53:16",
            "user": {
                "user_id": "c8c6ff00-452f-11e6-91e3-cbb55bd856a3",
                "first_name": "test",
                "last_name": "account"
            }
        }
 ]
```

This list is currently sorted alphanumerically by user_id (which is uc.to_user_id).

I am wondering what a better query might be to handle this.

Comment: Am trying to understand your question.. "The messages cannot be ordered by date_created because of the use of DISTINCT on uc.to_user_id" Why is that so? you can just add an order by created_at desc to your end of query. Then the result will be ordered descending by created date

Comment: Then it complains that:
ERROR: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
LINE 2: DISTINCT ON (uc.to_user_id)

This is because uc.created_at is not in the DISTINCT clause

Comment: What type and version of SQL?

Comment: Don't use `DISTINCT` unless you only want one row per `uc.to_user_id`. Use `ORDER BY uc.to_user_id, uc.created_at` to order your results by a `to_user_id` and then by the `created_at`.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I just want one row per uc.to_user_id. The messages should be uniquely shown for a list of recipients, so only one message per recipient should be shown.

Comment: I think you may need to give more details on what it is that you're expecting, but to me it looks like you are intending for there to be multiple calls to a to_user_id. Your current output isn't really set up the best way to sort like that.

Comment: Ah, so you want the most recent message to a user?

Comment: This is fairly simple with windowing functions. What flavor and version of SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT ON (uc.to_user_id)
        uc.id,
        uc.to_user_id,
        uc.created_at,
        u.first_name,
        u.last_name
FROM user_communication uc
LEFT JOIN "user" u ON (u.id = uc.to_user_id)
WHERE uc.from_user_id = :user_id)
ORDER BY created_at
```

Comment: Would this not just randomly select a single record for the `to_user_id` and then order them all by the `created_at` date for whatever record was selected?

Comment: Yes. If the where clause to limit the user id is removed, it can consider all the user ids

Comment: Right, but how does the subquery know which DISTINCT record to select? >>>> I'm guessing this is Postgres. `DISTINCT ON` looks pretty handy. But do you need the subquery? Can you not just do the `ORDER BY` with `to_user_id`,`created_at`?

Comment: Distinct On(A column) will not let you have order by B Column, that's why I suggested this way

Comment: Interesting. I'm not very familiar with Postgres, but the examples I looked at for `DISTINCT ON` did use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Yes, Distinct on (A col) order by A col. But OP is looking for Distinct on (A col) order by B col. So I suggested this

Comment: Hmmm..... Is that `ORDER BY` still accurate with modern versions of Postgres? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6fbb8/1  >>> Let me `ORDER BY` in both 9.3 and 9.6. I just had to use the [equivalent of] `to_user_id` as my first `ORDER BY`. It gave me the sorted results. Regardless, that's pretty handy. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165933/discussion-between-valli-and-shawn).

Comment: Ah yes, to get the ultimate sorting you would need that outer query. You can do the work inside the subquery, then just query and order those results how you want. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6fbb8/2  The more you know! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can share your schema as well for these 2 tables but just simplify the columns to what we need to see (i.e. we just need a handful of columns so we can focus on the main problem).

```
SELECT
        uc.to_user_id,
        uc.id,
        uc.to_user_id,
        uc.created_at,
        u.first_name,
        u.last_name
FROM user_communication uc
LEFT JOIN "user" u ON (u.id = uc.to_user_id)
WHERE uc.from_user_id = :user_id
GROUP BY uc.to_user_id
ORDER BY uc.to_user_id, uc.created_at
```

What kind of results do you get from the above? I'm curious what the duplicate rows look like that you want to get rid of with `DISTINCT` in this case.

With `GROUP BY` you can then sum or count certain attributes depending on what you want to do. Perhaps this won't help your problem so you may want to remove it.

Comment: For user_communications, the columns are:
id, from_user_id, to_user_id, type, data, created_at, updated_at.  
  
For user, the columns are:
id, company_id, email, password, first_name, last_name, phone, activated, country_code, data, created_at, updated_at, last_login_date, email_activated

Answer (score 0):

To only get the most recent message for each recipient, you can use window functions along the lines of:

```
SELECT * /* Be better to explicitly list your columns again. */
FROM (
    SELECT uc.id
        , uc.to_user_id
        , uc.created_at
        , u.first_name
        , u.last_name
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY uc.to_user_id ORDER BY uc.created_at DESC) as rn
    FROM user_communication uc
    LEFT JOIN "user" u ON (u.id = uc.to_user_id)
    WHERE uc.from_user_id = :user_id
) s1
WHERE s1.rn = 1
```

I'm not sure how PHP plays with window functions, but this should give you an idea how to solve this issue.